# gcc and clang under msys2 cannot resolve includes with absolute paths

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, mingw, msys2

I try to get tests generated by the cxxtest framework working under a MinGW environment managed by mysys2. The tool generates C++ files with absolute paths. However, gcc seems to be unable to resolve this absolute paths.

Here is a minimal example to demonstrate the problem:

```cpp
// file1.h
#include <iostream>
inline void hallo() { std::cout << "Hallo\n"; }
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "/home/phil/example/file1.h"

int main()
{
  hallo();
  return 0;
}
```

The file exists (at least the msys2 shell resolves the path):

```
$ ls /home/phil/example/file1.h
/home/phil/example/file1.h
```

... but calling g++ results in this error:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
main.cpp:1:38: fatal error: /home/phil/example/file1.h: No such file or directory
 #include "/home/phil/example/file1.h"
                                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

Same error with clang.

Under a full Linux environment, the example works. It also works if I replace the absolute path by a relative one (`#include "file1.h"`).

So, I assume the problem lies in the layer over Windows that is responsible to resolve paths. Not sure whether I should report it as a bug to the msys2 project, or whether it is a known problem. If it is a known problem, are there any workarounds (like setting `-I` options)?

(If possible, I would like to avoid replace the absolute paths, as they are in generated code by the cxxtest framework. Technically, running a postprocessing step on the generated files would be possible but seems like a hack in the long run.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are running compilers that use MinGW-w64 as their runtime environment, they don't recognize POSIX-style paths like that.  I think they actually interpret the root directory "/" to be "C:\".  Other than that, they would only recognize native Windows-style paths.

I recommend that you pass the argument `-I/home/phil/example` to your compiler from some program running in the msys-2.0.dll POSIX emulation runtime environment (e.g. /usr/bin/bash or /usr/bin/make).  The msys-2.0.dll runtime will then convert that argument to use a native Windows path so the compiler can understand it, and statements like `#include <file1.h>` will work.  Alternatively, you might try putting a Windows-style path in your source code, e.g. the path should start with `C:\`.

Note however that having absolute paths in source code or build scripts is a bad idea since it makes it harder to build the code on a different computer.  You could consider using environment variables or relative paths.

Comment: Agreed that the absolute paths are a bad idea. My current workaround is actually to run "sed" and remove the prefix, so they become relative paths. I think I should try to get a patch in the cxxtest project to stop generating the absolute paths (at least with an opt-in switch). Working around seems not worth it from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MinGW compiler that Cygwin provides as a package. (In other words, forget the MSYS environment; work under Cygwin, but build the code as before, in the MinGW style.)

Then you should be able to have include references `/home/phil`; it will just resolve to `C:\Cygwin\home\phil` or wherever your Cygwin root is.

Actually, it might be possible under MSYS also (which, after all, is just the descendant of an old for of Cygwin). You just have to figure out what `/home/phil` is referring to, create that tree and work under there.

Comment: Oh, actually msys2 proved very useful, especially as it was the only way how I got TBB (Intel Threading Building Blocks) working. The testing part is a relative small issue. Under Cygwin, I run into more problems. By the way, as you write msys, it could be a misunderstanding, as I'm using msys2, which is a recent rewrite of msys.

Comment: MSYS2 is again a Cygwin fork; and Cygwin has the MinGW-w64 compilers as a package.  It would be great of MSYS2 had a home page where it describes the concrete list of issues that it solves over using Cygwin.