# C++: `error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant` before `__FILE__` in `fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)` when compiling gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64, msys2

This is a continuation of trying to compile a license-free GPL version of the Microchip XC32 microcontroller g++ XC32 v4.35 cross-compiler from source.

See [my Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77414776/4561887), and my repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler.

Note that this builds perfectly to completion on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 with `gcc --version` `gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`.

However, when compiling on Windows in the MSYS2 UCRT64 environment (set up [per my instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407282/4561887)) with `gcc --version` `gcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0`, I now get the following error in `gcc/gcc/system.h`:

```
./../../pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/prefix.c
../../../pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/system.h:737:30: error: expected identifier before string constant
  737 | #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
../../../pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/system.h:737:30: error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant
../../../pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/system.h:737:30: error: expected identifier before string constant
  737 | #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
../../../pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/system.h:737:30: error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1112: prefix.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/gabriel/GS/dev/Microchip_XC32_Compiler/xc32-v4.35-src/pic32m-build/gcc/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:4290: all-gcc] Error 2
```

[Here is the `system.h` file I am using, at line 737](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler/blob/main/xc32-v4.35-src/pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/system.h#L733-L737):

```c
/* Redefine abort to report an internal error w/o coredump, and
   reporting the location of the error in the source file.  */
extern void fancy_abort (const char *, int, const char *)
                     ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN ATTRIBUTE_COLD;
#define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
```

This definition of `abort()` is getting called, for instance, inside a C++ template class [in `fibonacci_heap.h` line 460, here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler/blob/main/xc32-v4.35-src/pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/fibonacci_heap.h#L460):

```cpp
template<class K, class V>
V*
fibonacci_heap<K,V>::delete_node (fibonacci_node<K,V> *node, bool release)
{
  V *ret = node->m_data;

  /* To perform delete, we just make it the min key, and extract.  */
  replace_key (node, m_global_min_key);
  if (node != m_min)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Can't force minimum on fibheap.\n");
      abort ();  // <=========== HERE ===========
    }
  extract_min (release);

  return ret;
}
```

How do I resolve this build error?

And, why is it occurring on Windows, but not on Linux?

---

### Additional research:

1. Useful Google search: [msys gcc abort fancy_abort error: expected identifier before string constant](https://www.google.com/search?q=msys+gcc+abort+fancy_abort+error%3A+expected+identifier+before+string+constant&oq=msys+gcc+abort+fancy_abort+error%3A+expected+identifier+before+string+constant&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCTMxODAwajBqOagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1)
2. Possible bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/974/
3. Possible fix: https://github.com/yosshin4004/xdev68k/blob/main/build_m68k-toolchain.sh#L199-L210

   ```bash
   #
   #   新しい mingw 環境では以下のようなエラーとなる。
   #       ../../../src/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/system.h:743:30: error: expected identifier before string constant
   #       743 | #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
   #   応急処置として、問題を起こす行を除去する。
   #   abort() は stdlib.h 内で宣言された実装のままの挙動となる。
   #
   if [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5)" == "MINGW" ]; then
       cat ${SRC_DIR}/${GCC_DIR}/gcc/system.h |\
       perl -e 'my $before="#define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)";my $after="/* $before */";$before=quotemeta($before);while(<>){$_=~s/$before/$after/g;print $_;}' > ${SRC_DIR}/${GCC_DIR}/gcc/system.h.tmp;
       mv ${SRC_DIR}/${GCC_DIR}/gcc/system.h.tmp ${SRC_DIR}/${GCC_DIR}/gcc/system.h
   fi
   ```

   [Translation of the comments from Japanese to English:](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%23%0A%23%09%E6%96%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%20mingw%20%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82%0A%23%09%09..%2F..%2F..%2Fsrc%2Fgcc-10.2.0%2Fgcc%2Fsystem.h%3A743%3A30%3A%20error%3A%20expected%20identifier%20before%20string%20constant%0A%23%09%09743%20%7C%20%23define%20abort()%20fancy_abort%20(__FILE__%2C%20__LINE__%2C%20__FUNCTION__)%0A%23%09%E5%BF%9C%E6%80%A5%E5%87%A6%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%80%81%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%99%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%92%E9%99%A4%E5%8E%BB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82%0A%23%09abort()%20%E3%81%AF%20stdlib.h%20%E5%86%85%E3%81%A7%E5%AE%A3%E8%A8%80%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82&op=translate)

   ```bash
   #
   # In the new mingw environment, the following error will occur.
   # ../../../src/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/system.h:743:30: error: expected identifier before string constant
   # 743 | #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
   # As a workaround, remove the offending line.
   # abort() behaves as the implementation declared in stdlib.h.
   ```

   The code above simply finds `#define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)` in `gcc/system.h`, and comments it out as `/* #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__) */`, thereby removing it.

   Just commenting out this offending macro define seems really hacky. I don't fully understand the repercussions of this change.

Comment: Well, standard library includes an `abort()` function that terminates the program.  The only thing that macro does is provide an error message saying where it happened.  Removing the macro allows the library function to run instead.  It's a safe change.

Comment: @TimRoberts, thanks. Where is this `abort()` macro/function providing the error message? To the user when _compiling_ with the cross-compiler I am compiling now? Or is this extra error message somehow getting injected into the binary compiled _by_ the cross-compiler, running on the target compiled for by the cross-compiler I'm compiling? ie: will commenting this out change _my cross-compiler_ I'm compiling, or change code compiled by the cross-compiler I'm compiling?

Comment: It's a runtime abort.  I assume it's sent to stdout.

Comment: @TimRoberts, the _cross-compiler's_ stdout? --while compiling for a microcontroller target later?

Comment: Well, yes.  It's apparently a MINGW problem, and the thing MINGW is compiling is the cross-compiler.

Comment: Sounds good. We have 3 layers here, so I was confused. I am running a compiler (1) which is compiling a cross-compiler (2) to compile for a target microcontroller (3). So, I wasn't sure if making this change would change how the target program (3) operates or how how the cross-compiler (2) operates. If it just changes how the cross-compiler (2) operates, then it's a pretty benign change, as the cross-compiler should only call `abort()` if it has a run-time bug and crashes while compiling for the target (3). If this were to change (3) somehow, however, that's a much bigger deal.

Comment: Yes, it's very meta.  I don't think we KNOW at this point whether the cross-compiler that you're compiling has the same problem.  I suspect it does not.  So, it's just that your cross-compiler will produce a less useful message if it encounters an internal error, which you are unlikely to ever encounter.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the cross-compiler to me. A translation unit that includes a standard library header may not #define or #undef names declared in any standard library header.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, you mean a bug in the MSYS2 gcc compiler on Windows, right? This is what I'm calling the "compiler". It's compiling a PIC32 mcu cross-compiler.

Comment: No the PIC32 mcu cross-compiler has a bug, it has `#define abort()`, not gcc. It is UB to `#define` any standard names.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, in that case, commenting out the define like I did [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77435824/4561887) is _fixing_ this bug? Also, any idea why it built fine in Linux Ubuntu but not in Windows MSYS2?

Comment: Yes it is the right thing to do. Undefined behaviour is undefined, it can work as expected here but not there, today but not tomorrow. I don't know whether there is a problem with MSYS2 gcc that would also prevent legitimate cases (not involving reserved names such as `abort`) from working.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem on a small example. Just copying the `#define` to a short program and then calling `abort` works as expected. I don't have much time to try it on the cross-compiler, sorry. If you want to debug it further, try to isolate the failing compilation command, modify it so that it saves the preprocessed file, and look at the result.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, the replies to [my bug report here](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/19036) are very useful. I added a section to the bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77435824/4561887) titled, "Update: better fix", too. I haven't tried out that recommended fix yet.

Comment: *The `IXMLDOMDocument` class has a member function named `abort()`, which gets affected by our `abort()` macro in "system.h".* Just what one would expect. But to ditch the `#define`? Nooo, it's so clever and cute and shiny! Sigh. (End rant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big thanks to @Tim Roberts and "@n. m. could be an AI" for their help and comments under the question which contributed to this answer.

Solution:

**Comment out `#define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)` in `system.h` to make gcc compile.**

Simply commenting out the `abort()` define, [as done here](https://github.com/yosshin4004/xdev68k/blob/main/build_m68k-toolchain.sh#L199-L210) and as documented at the bottom of my question, worked.

There seems to be a bug in MSYS2 in Windows stopping the build from working with it defined, so simply open up `xc32-v4.35-src/pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/system.h`, find [this on line 737](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler/blob/main/xc32-v4.35-src/pic32m-source/gcc/gcc/system.h#L737):

```c
#define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
```

...and comment it out like this:

```c
/* #define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__) */
```

The build now goes to completion when I run `time Microchip_XC32_Compiler/build-xc32-v4.35m.sh`, and the MSYS2 UCRT64 gcc toolchain is able to build the PIC32 mcu gcc cross-compiler to completion!

### Is this hack safe?

Yes, we think so.

There are 3 layers here: I'm using the MSYS2 UCRT GCC compiler on Windows (layer 1) to compile the Microchip XC32 PIC32 gcc microcontroller cross-compiler (layer 2), which will cross-compile programs (on Windows in this Q&A, though I have it built on Linux Ubuntu too) for PIC32 microcontrollers (layer 3).

Per the discussion with @Tim Roberts under my question (for example, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77435355/c-error-expected-or-before-string-constant-before-file-in?noredirect=1#comment136515164_77435355), and others), we think this change is pretty benign and should only affect the layer 2 XC32 cross-compiler (which is what is being compiled in this Q&A), by making it produce less-useful runtime error messages (missing the `__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__` content) if it crashes while running and compiling for a layer 3 target. So, not a big deal. Layer 3 (the target mcu) remains unaffected. Layer 2 will just have less-useful error messages if it crashes. But, that's unlikely. I can't recall the gcc compiler ever crashing on me. It has produced tons of compilation errors while compiling, of course, but I can't recall having seen it ever produce a run-time crash and output its own internal error. This is what we are talking about. That's the part my change has affected.

### Other fixes

Tony Yu on SourceForge has what looks like a [good alternative fix too, here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/974/#1198).

Basically, just comment out `#define abort() fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)` in `system.h`, like I did, but then also replace all calls to `abort()` in `gcc/gcc.c` with `fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)` instead. The challenge here is replacing all of the correct `abort()` calls, not just here, but anywhere they may be calling `fancy_abort()`. So...that seems hard. I think just commenting it out is fine instead.

### Bug reports

I opened this bug report. Feel free to leave a comment: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/4142

### Update: better fix

Apply this patch to a bunch of gcc files: https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2023-January/609514.html. This link comes from a reply to my bug report above.

**Basically, you should always `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before calling `#include <windows.h>`. This, apparently, is the proper fix.**

Reason: from here: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=902c755930326cb4405672aa3ea13c35c653cbff (emphasis added):

> Always define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before `<windows.h>`
>
> Recently, mingw-w64 has got updated `<msxml.h>` from Wine which is included
> indirectly by `<windows.h>` if `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is not defined. The
> `IXMLDOMDocument` class has a member function named `abort()`, which gets
> affected by our `abort()` macro in **"system.h"**.
>
> `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` should, nevertheless, always be defined. This
> can exclude 'APIs such as Cryptography, DDE, RPC, Shell, and Windows
> Sockets' [1], and speed up compilation of these files a bit.

So, I plan to manually do the fix, produce a `git diff`-based patch file, commit the patch file, and then make the patch via `git apply` (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77601080/4561887)) as part of the build script process.